# Strange result when comparing properties

Tags: javascript, equals

Could you please explain me the following. Trying to compare object attributes: newName of the `v` and `rowData` objects. Got back values `report3` and `report2`, however on comparison `(rowData.newName === v.newName)` these values are equal??!! Please refer to the console message below

Values are strings, belong to different objects.

```
console.log('== NEW NAME OF THE VALE OF TABLE ==');
console.log(v.nameNew); // which is report3
console.log('== NEW NAME OF THE DATA OF THE ROW ==');
console.log(rowData.nameNew); // which is report2
console.log('== IDIOT PROOF TEST ');
console.log(rowData.newName === v.newName);
```

CONSOLE LOG:

```
== NEW NAME OF THE VALE OF TABLE ==
Report3
== NEW NAME OF THE DATA OF THE ROW ==
Report2
== IDIOT PROOF TEST
true
```

Comment: What are the types of the `nameNew`s? How are they declared?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not sure if you mistyped it but you log

```
console.log(v.nameNew);
```

You then compare

```
v.newName
```

If you made a mistake and are actually comparing the right variables, can you post more code (how you are declaring them and assigning them)

Comment: And since the `newName` properties are both undefined, they pass the `===` test.

Comment: Cheers, mate. looking forward for my holidyas, what a mistake!

Comment: Mistakes like that are easy to make and sometimes hard to detect, especially in js!